# Inherit from ResourceManager and replace default ResourceManager

Tags: .net, winforms

I would like to inherit from ResourceManager to replace the default ResourceManager. The reason is, that I need to read control captions and other texts from a database. In cases where there is no database entry the default captions should be read from the application's resources.

For that I would like to write a custom ResourceManager and overwrite e.g. the GetString-method.

I know how to inherit from ResourceManager, but I don't know how to replace the default ResourceManager.

I found [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759898/342594), but I can't get it to compile.

To be honest, I don't know if I'm going the wrong direction. All sources I found are rather old. Maybe replacing the ResourceManager isn't a good idea, so if somebody has a better approach I would be happy to hear about it as well.

Thanks,
Sascha

Comment: What is wrong with simple class, which can be fill with data from database and bound to the windows form?

Comment: @Fabio I don't know, if there is something wrong with what you suggest, because I never used databinding in such a scenario, but I will look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.